# Add 'is-page-scrolled' class on vertical scroll with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to migrate some jQuery code to pure JavaScript. The current jQuery code toggles a class named `is-page-scrolled` in the `body` element when the user scrolls down to a specific offset set in a `data` attribute in the body element named `data-page-scrolled-offset`. If the user scrolls up again to the top of the page, the class is toggled off.

**My working jQuery code:**

```
var scrolled_page_offset = parseInt( $( 'body' ).data( 'pageScrolledOffset' ) );
var scrolled_page = function() {
    var scroll_top = window.pageYOffset;
    $( 'body' ).toggleClass( 'is-page-scrolled', scroll_top > scrolled_page_offset );
};

$( window ).on( 'scroll', function() {
    scrolled_page();
} );

scrolled_page();
```

**My non-working pure JavaScript code:**

```
var scrolled_page_offset = parseInt( document.body.dataset.pageScrolledOffset );
var scrolled_page = function() {
    var scroll_top = window.pageYOffset;
    if ( scroll_top > scrolled_page_offset ) {
        document.body.classList.toggle( 'is-page-scrolled' );
    }
};

window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function() {
    scrolled_page();
} );

scrolled_page();
```

My proposed pure Javascript code is not working as expected because it toggles the class on and off intermittently when the user scrolls down in the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: jQuery's `toggleClass()` is setting the class on/off based on the `scroll_top > scrolled_page_offset`. Your `if` + `toggle()` is inverting the on/off state of the class every time `scroll_top > scrolled_page_offset` is true. You could extend the `if()` to also check that it's not already in the desired state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation of the current problem, copied from my comment:

> jQuery's `toggleClass()` is setting the class on/off based on the
> `scroll_top > scrolled_page_offset`. Your `if` + `toggle()` is
> inverting the on/off state of the class every time `scroll_top > scrolled_page_offset` is `true`.

If we compare "does the class exist" to "do we want the class to exist", we avoid accidentally inverting the state of the class.

If this example I've added:

```
  const isEnabled = document.body.classList.contains(className)
  const shouldBeEnabled = scroll_top > scrolled_page_offset
  if (shouldBeEnabled !== isEnabled) { ... }
```

Which will only run the `if` when we expect the class to change.

(In this demo, the background turns green to show when the class is added)

```js
// Set up the demo, ignore this
document.body.dataset.pageScrolledOffset = 200;
//

const className = 'is-page-scrolled'
const scrolled_page_offset = parseInt(document.body.dataset.pageScrolledOffset);
const scrolled_page = function() {
  const scroll_top = window.pageYOffset;

  const isEnabled = document.body.classList.contains(className)
  const shouldBeEnabled = scroll_top > scrolled_page_offset

  if (shouldBeEnabled !== isEnabled) {
    document.body.classList.toggle(className);
  }
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  scrolled_page();
});
scrolled_page();
```

```css
#scrollable {
  height: 10000px;
}

.is-page-scrolled {
  background: #060;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollable">
  Scroll down
</div>
```